# Conditional networkx pathfinding

Tags: python, python-2.7, graph-theory, networkx

I've made the question title as broad as possible, but the following is a particular problem which illustrates the actual problem I'm trying to solve.

Suppose `g` is a `networkx.MultiGraph` where each edge is either colored red or blue.  What would a function look like which takes `g` and two nodes and efficiently finds paths which meet the following two conditions:

1. the first and last edges are red, and
2. the colour of edges along the path alternates red, blue, red, blue, ...

NB: The criteria are such that the paths may not be a subset of the simple path[s] returned by the standard `networkx` pathfinding functions, so it isn't possible to simply filter the result of `networkx.all_paths` after the fact.

**An example**

Problem: In the following graph, find a path from `b` to `a` subject to the conditions given above.

[image: A coloured multigraph]

[Code to create such a graph.](https://bitbucket.org/snippets/adam_fuller/qRGaB)

Answer: bBAa, bBBbAa, etc..  (bAa is shorter but does not meet the criteria.)

**A tiny example**

Problem: In the following graph, find a path from `a` to `a` subject to the conditions given above.

[image]

Answer: aAAa.

Answer (score 1):

Make two copies of your nodes: X versions and Y versions.  For every red edge from a to b in your original graph, connect X_a to Y_b and X_b to Y_a.  Similarly, for every blue edge from a to b in your original graph, connect Y_a to X_b and Y_b to X_a.  Then to find all the paths you want between a and b, find all simple paths (using `networkx`'s `all_simple_paths`) between X_a and Y_b.

E.g., the path in your question is actually:  X_a -> Y_A -> X_A -> Y_a

```
import networkx as nx


def bidirectional(l):
    for a, b in l:
        yield a, b
        yield b, a

red_edges = [('X' + a, 'Y' + b)
             for a, b in bidirectional(['bB', 'aA', 'cC'])]
blue_edges = [('Y' + a, 'X' + b)
              for a, b in bidirectional(
                      ['bA', 'BA', 'AA', 'BB', 'AC', 'BC', 'Bc', 'CC', 'Ca'])]

G = nx.DiGraph(red_edges + blue_edges)
paths = ["".join([n[1]
                  for n in path])
         for path in nx.all_simple_paths(G, 'Xb', 'Ya')]
print(paths)
```

prints

```
['bBBbAa', 'bBAa', 'bBCcBbAa', 'bBcCBbAa', 'bBcCaABbAa', 'bBcCaAAa', 'bBcCaACcBbAa', 'bBcCAa', 'bBcCCcBbAa']
```

Note that I ended up using a directed graph to maintain the distinction between red and blue links.

Comment: Are you using "a" and "b" to mean any two neighbours in general?  In general no edges will connect `a` and `b` in my first example graph.  I do like the idea of copying the graph, implementing the colour logic with with new edges between X and Y, and finding simple paths on that new graph.

Comment: @AdamFuller: What do you mean?

Comment: I mean, in your answer, it seems like you're using the letters "a" and "b" as generic node names, when they already appear in my example.  Your method also seems to rely upon knowing the direction of an edge, which is unknown during the path search.  I think you're onto something though.  I'm developing something similar but it will be much clearer when I have a visualization.  Watch this space.

Comment: Although your implementation works in this case, it relies upon `DiGraph` which does not allow parallel edges.  I need a method which is robust for MultiGraphs where there might be red and blue parallel edges between two nodes.  It also needs some work to turn it into a function with a signature like `nx.all_simple_graphs`.

Comment: @AdamFuller: Of course it allows "parallel edges" and multigraphs work fine too.  Did you try it?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot give you the exact answer. However, I can tell you that you cannot use dijkstra. Dijkstra's algorithm does the sumatory of the cost values of the edges. The sumatory operation is commutative (order does not matter). But in your problem, the order does matter. For instance,  dijkstra will treat the paths red-blue-red  or red-red-blue in the same way.
Therefore, by using Dijkstra will be imposible to solve the problem.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying the limitations of Dijkstra's algorithm.  I've edited my question to remove references to it.

Comment: @AdamFuller: Dijkstra's algorithm is fine for this problem if you looking for the shortest path.